# Margin in between a Photoset

Tags: html, css, margin, margins

I need some little help:

I want to have a constant margin (10px) between post and in between photos of a photoset (also 10px). 
My problem: If a post is a photoset, the margins of the most bottom photo and of the margin of the entire post add up to 20px.

I want to keep the post margin for videos, text, etc for.

Here is the page:

http://juliuschoenleber.tumblr.com/

The top image is a single image (but also could be a video for example).
You can see the 'double margin' to the following photoset.

Head Code:

```
.post{margin-bottom:10px;width:500px; font-size:{text:text     
size}px;width:500px;}

.post img{width:500px;margin-bottom:10px;}
```

Body Code:

```
{block:Photo}
<div class="post"align="center">
{block:IndexPage}
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
<div class="post"align="center">
{block:Photos} 
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
{/block:Photos} 
</div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

I tried different things. But it only messes up the margins even more.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please place your mouse over your tags and read them. One tag is not supposed to be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.post img {
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.post img:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```